# Java Hibernate Apache Derby - Table/View does not exist

Tags: java, apache, derby

The table "customer" is under the default schema "APP". When I run, I get an error:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'CUSTOMER' does not exist.

The same jdbcUrl works through DriverManager.getConnection through.

I tried to include the schema name as part of jdbcUrl:

```
<property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:derby:web_customer_tracker; user=app" />, but still no luck.

<!-- Step 1: Define Database DataSource / connection pool -->
<bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
      destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:derby:web_customer_tracker" />

    <!-- these are connection pool properties for C3P0 -->
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="30000" />
</bean> 

<!-- Step 2: Setup Hibernate session factory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.luv2code.springdemo.entity" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
       <props>
          <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</prop>
          <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
       </props>
    </property>
```

```
<!-- Step 3: Setup Hibernate transaction manager -->
<bean id="myTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Corrected code and error formatting.